# Updating OpportunityLineItem always results in INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY

Tags: apex, error, dml

Exact error that I'm receiving:

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id
>   00kO0000006gU4fIAE; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, invalid
>   cross reference id: []

Exact object I'm updating: (I did have real fields, but even just updating an object with only the Id, it gives the same error)

> |OpportunityLineItem:{Id=00kO0000006gU4fIAE} (from debug logs)

I've got a static Apex class that is trying to update existing `OpportunityLineItem`(s) but every time I attempt an update operation with the `Id` set it always gives me a cross reference Id error (originally it was actually updating more than just Id, but I stripped everything else out and same error). When pasting the Id into Salesforce it brings up the Opportunity Product so it should be correct.

Am I missing some weird complication with `OpportunityLineItem`?

**Note**: I am running in Sandbox.

**Note2**: Inserts work fine (would deleting everything and only doing inserts be a valid strategy? Seems hacky to me)
[image: Opportunity Product Proof]

Comment: can you post your code

Comment: Did you see where the error was in the debug logs, was it immediately after the update? If not you could have other code running on the update that could be causing it...Trace the debug logs. Without seeing the full debug logs or your code it is impossible to say

Comment: I think this was an error on Salesforce side, the problem disappeared when production environments got Spring '17 (despite this being on Sandbox). No code was changed, but it started working....